# C# byte addition operation

Tags: c#, .net

Could someone point me, why here:

```
Byte b = 100; 
b = (Byte)(b+200);
```

I have to use explicit type conversion. But here

```
Byte b = 100;
b += 200;
```

I don't need to do this?

Does compiler generate different IL code for this two cases? And which case is better?

Comment: From memory, they are identical - have you tried with reflector / ildasm, though?

Comment: I just compiled and inspected with ildasm.exe and they are in fact identical. See Mehrdad's answer for the reason for the different treatment by the compiler.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the standard permits it (see the second case below):

> #### 14.14.2 Compound assignment
>
> An operation of the form `x` *op*`=` `y` is processed by applying binary operator overload resolution (§14.2.4) as if the operation was written `x` *op* `y`. Then,
>
> - If the return type of the selected operator is implicitly convertible to the type of `x`, the operation is evaluated as `x = x` *op* `y`, except that `x` is evaluated only once.
> - Otherwise, if the selected operator is a predefined operator, if the return type of the selected operator is explicitly convertible to the type of `x`, and if `y` is implicitly convertible to the type of `x` or the operator is a shift operator, then the operation is evaluated as `x = (T)(x`  *op* `y)`, where `T` is the type of `x`, except that `x` is evaluated only once.
> - Otherwise, the compound assignment is invalid, and a compile-time error occurs.

The IL code should be essentially identical in this case. Of course, if evaluating `b` has side effects, it will be evaluated twice in the `b = (byte)b + 200` case and only once when using compound assignment.

Answer (score 6):

This is a FAQ in the C# tag, hard to find the duplicate.  The need for the cast is relevant first.  The underlying reason is that the CLI only specifies a limited number of valid types for the Opcodes.Add IL instruction.  Only operands of type Int32, Int64, Single, Double and IntPtr are supported.  IntPtr is special as well, the C# language forbids using that one.

So the C# compiler *has* to use an implicit conversion to uplift the byte to a type that the operator supports.  It will pick Int32 as the closest compatible type.  The result of the addition is Int32.  Which does not fit back into a byte without truncating the result, throwing away the extra bits.  An obvious example is 255 + 1, the result is 256 in Int32 but doesn't fit a Byte and yields 0 when stored.

That's a problem, the language designers didn't like that truncation to happen without you explicitly acknowledging that you are aware of the consequences.  A cast is required to convince the compiler that you're aware.  Bit of a cop-out of course, you tend to produce the cast mechanically *without* thinking much about the consequences.  But that makes it your problem, not Microsoft's :)

The rub was the += operator, a very nice operator to write condense code.  Resembles the brevity of the *var* keyword.  Rock and a hard place however, where do you put the cast?  It just doesn't work so they punted the problem and allowed truncation without a cast.

Notable is the way VB.NET works, it doesn't require a cast.  But it gives a guarantee that C# doesn't provide by default, it will generate an OverflowException when the result doesn't fit.  Pretty nice, but that check doesn't come for free.

Designing clean languages is a very hard problem.  The C# team did an excellent job, warts not withstanding.  Otherwise the kind of warts brought on by processor design.  IL has these type restrictions because that's what real 32-bit processors have too, particularly the RISC designs that were popular in the 90s.  Their internal registers can only handle 32-bit integers and IEEE-754 floating point.  And only permit smaller types in loads and stores.  The Intel x86 core is very popular and actually permits basic operations on smaller types.  But that's mostly a historical accident due to Intel keeping the design compatible through the 8-bit 8080 and 16-bit 8086 generations.  It doesn't come for free, 16-bit operations costs an extra cpu cycle.  To be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This because of the implicit conversion rules.

When you have a binary `+` operator the result is converted to the larger of the two types.
The literal `200` is of type int and therefore the type of the expression `b+200` is int.
The assignment operator `=` doesn't do implicit conversion, but rather throws error. As in

```
        int x = 10;
        Byte b = x; //Error
```

In the second case the `+=` operator expects byte, so 200 (which is of type int, but fits into byte) is implicitly converted to byte, because the compiler knows it can. The following won't compile, because the compile doesn't know if x will fit in a byte or not.

```
        Byte b = 100;
        int x = 200;
        b += x; //Error
```

If you make x a const then it compiles:

```
        Byte b = 100;
        const int x = 200;
        b += x;  //OK
```

Answer (score 0):

The spec calls this out as a specific case of the compound assignment operator:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691316%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Specifically, bullet 2:

- Otherwise, if the selected operator is a predefined operator, if the
  return type of the selected operator is explicitly convertible to the
  type of x, and if y is implicitly convertible to the type of x, then
  the operation is evaluated as x = (T)(x op y), where T is the type of
  x, except that x is evaluated only once.

> The second rule above permits x op= y to be evaluated as x = (T)(x op
>   y) in certain contexts. The rule exists such that the predefined
>   operators can be used as compound operators when the left operand is
>   of type sbyte, byte, short, ushort, or char. Even when both arguments
>   are of one of those types, the predefined operators produce a result
>   of type int, as described in Section 7.2.6.2. Thus, without a cast it
>   would not be possible to assign the result to the left operand.