# Adding bytes rolls over to 0 or continues to 256?

Tags: c#, byte

Can someone explain the outputs of below code?

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        byte b1 = 190;
        byte b2 = 66;
        var b3 = b1 + b2;
        Console.WriteLine(b3);
        b1 += b2;
        Console.WriteLine(b1);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
256
0
```

Why does first additions gives **256**, but the second one gives **0**?

Comment: b3 is an int (max value 2 147 483 647), b1 is a byte (max value 255)

Comment: Another relevant info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9457655/5311735

Comment: I see no strange outputs. Also, read the docs and search: Byte.MaxValue is 255, then a rollover occurs. Don't know who upvoted, but this is not a unique, well-researched question.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think it's somewhat confusing that `b1 = b1 + b2` will not compile, but `b1 += b2` will silently cast int to byte.

Comment: @Evk if they tried that, they'd have had a compiler error to start their search with and to mention in their question.